# Using Variables in Dfunction VBA

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba

```
Y = DMax("[ID]", "Table1", "Len(date) = 0")
A = DMin("[ID]", "Table1", "Len(date) > 0")
B = DLookup("[Duration]", "Table1", "[ID] = [Y]")
C = DLookup("[Due_date]", "Table1", "[ID] = [A]")
E = [C] - [B]
```

Variable B errors out. (And then C and E would as well) Is there a way to use Y in my criteria for variable B?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Square brackets denote a host-specific expression resolved at run-time. Remove the square brackets. `E = C - B` ...and use explicitly declared local variables, with meaningful identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May also try

```
B = DLookup("[Duration]", "Table1", "[ID] =" & Y)
C = DLookup("[Due_date]", "Table1", "[ID] =" & A)
```

or  if ID is string

```
   B = DLookup("[Duration]", "Table1", "[ID] ='" & Y & "'")
   C = DLookup("[Due_date]", "Table1", "[ID] ='" & A & "'")
```

Comment: Okay, that's a huge help! Thank you!

Comment: When I put B in a textbox, "Text8.Value = B", it shows up as a date similar to 1/2/1900. However, Duration is formatted as days in table 1, so it should be writing 3 days. I also get an error for E = C - B, maybe because it doesn't know B is days and C is a short date?

Comment: i could not get it clearly. I expect duration in days should be numeric and also to be formatted as number. However you may try `E=Dateadd("d",-B,C)` to get  E as date (if B is number & C is date)  if both are date and the difference is required as result then try DateDiff function. i.e. `DateDiff(interval, date1, date2)`, .

Comment: Yes! the date add function did it! Thank you!!